# Some test cases not running but some are in terms of probability

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a program in which it rolls five dice and assigns a hand to the rolls. i.e. nothing, a pair, two pair, three of a kind, full house, four of a kind, five of a kind. The code runs 1000000 times and gives percentage chances for each roll. Below I have attached general percentages my code should output near:

```
Case 1, None alike, is 0.092533
Case 2, One pair, is 0.462799
Case 3, Two pair, is 0.231789
Case 4, Three of a kind, is 0.154192
Case 5, Full house, is 0.038595
Case 6, Four of a kind, is 0.019316
Case 7, Five of a kind, is 0.000776
```

However my code gives the following output:

```
Case 1, None alike is 0.093099
Case 2, One pair is 0.384768
Case 3, Two pair is 0.076921
Case 4, Three of a kind is 0.15485
Case 5, Full House is 0.270349
Case 6, Four of a kind is 0.019281
Case 7, Five of a kind is7.33E-4
```

I don't understand why my programs percentages are off for one pair, two pairs, and full house.  I have gone through and tested my logic but it is sound from what I have seen. Originally, my one pair was correct but my two pair was 0.0. Below is my original logic which causes the two pair to be 0 and my pair to be correct.

I, however, changed it to the current logic to get the current output. I would appreciate another set of eyes to take a look and let me know if they could catch something. Below is my code:

Comment: Would like to ask that what does "Full House" mean here?

Comment: It means a group of 3 of the same numbers and a pair of another number.

Comment: Please check my answer!

Comment: *"Below is my code:"* - no it isn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change 1 :**

```
if (hand < 6) {
                int counter3 = 0;
                int counter2 = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                     if (counts[j] == 3) {
                        counter3++;
                     }
                     if (counts [j] == 2) {
                        counter2++;
                     } 
                }
                if (counter3 == 1 && counter2 == 1) {
                    hand = 5;
                }
            }
```

**Change 2:**

```
if (hand < 4) {
                int newcounter = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    if (counts[j] == 2) {
                       newcounter++;
                    }
                }
                if (newcounter==2) {
                        hand = 3;
                    }
                if (newcounter == 1) { hand = 2; }
}
```

**Change 3 :**

Please remove `if( hand < 3)` part of code.

**Updated my answer.** In your code the `counter` variable (when you're trying to check "full house") was becoming 2 due to two pairs (ex : counts = 020200) not due to full house (ex: counts = 300200). Hence, it wasn't counting the two pairs in the following code where it was supposed to because `hand` was already becoming 5, so it didn't go inside any other `if` parts below although it was supposed to go inside `if(hand<3)`. Hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: I tried your logic but it still doesn't seem to change the output. I'm still getting the same solution.

Comment: I corrected the same issue as pointed out by `@Ke Zhu` in his answer.

Comment: When I try your code above, I get an error because newcounter is defined in the first if statement but used in the second if statement. When I try to change the second if statement to a new variable, I get a wrong answer similar to the one I had before. When I place the counter initialization-outside both if statements, I get 0 for both two pair and pair.

Comment: Great! Code works on all cases now. I'm a little confused as to how your code fixed all the issues at once. Do you mind breaking it down? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for many edits. I've updated the answer and explained the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See comment in code

```
   if (hand < 4) {
        int newcounter = 0;
        boolean firstp = false;
        boolean secondp = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            firstp = false;
            secondp = false;
            if (counts[j] == 2) {
               firstp = true; <---- THIS 
            }
            if (counts[j] == 2) {
               secondp = true; <---- AND THIS will always hit together as j never changes from the first if to second if
          //     break;
            }
        }
            if (firstp && secondp) {
                hand = 3; <---- firstp always equal to secondp, I would be surprised to see hand ever = 2
            }
    }
```

I modified your code. The original logic is a little bit messy. I made some slight improvement but hopefully better. Not perfect though.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PokerDice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double none = 0;
        double  pair = 0;
        double twop = 0;
        double  threep = 0;
        double  full = 0;
        double fourp = 0;
        double fivep = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<=1000000; i++) {
            int [] rolls = new int[5];
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                rolls[j] = (int)(1 + (Math.random()*(6)));
            }
            int[] counts = Counts(rolls);

            boolean has_two = false;
            boolean has_three = false;

            none++;

            for (int j = 0; j < counts.length; j++) {

                if (counts[j] == 4) {
                    fourp++;
                    none--;
                    break;
                }
                if (counts[j] == 5) {
                    fivep++;
                    none--;
                    break;
                }
                if (counts[j] == 3) {
                    has_three = true;

                    if (has_two) {
                        full++;
                        pair--;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        none--;
                        threep++;
                    }
                }
                if (counts[j] == 2) {
                    if (has_two) {
                        twop++;
                        pair--;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (has_three) {
                        full++;
                        threep--;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        has_two = true;
                        pair++;
                        none--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fivep/=1000000;
        fourp/=1000000;
        full/=1000000;
        threep/=1000000;
        twop/=1000000;
        pair/=1000000;
        none/=1000000;
        System.out.println("Poker Dice Probability Calculator");
        System.out.println("Running 1,000,000 trials");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Case 1, None alike is "+none);
        System.out.println("Case 2, One pair is "+pair);
        System.out.println("Case 3, Two pair is "+twop);
        System.out.println("Case 4, Three of a kind is "+threep);
        System.out.println("Case 5, Full House is "+full);
        System.out.println("Case 6, Four of a kind is "+fourp);
        System.out.println("Case 7, Five of a kind is"+fivep);             
    }
    public static int[] Counts (int [] rolled) {
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        int five = 0;
        int six = 0;
        int len = rolled.length;
        int [] rolltimes = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
            if (rolled [i] == 1) {
                one++;
            }
             else if (rolled [i] == 2) {
                two++;
            }
            else if (rolled [i] == 3) {
                three++;
            }
            else if (rolled [i] == 4) {
                four++;
            }
            else if (rolled [i] == 5) {
                five++;
            }
            else if (rolled [i] == 6) {
                six++;
            }
        }
        rolltimes[0] = one;
        rolltimes[1] = two;
        rolltimes[2] = three;
        rolltimes[3] = four;
        rolltimes[4] = five;
        rolltimes[5] = six;
        return rolltimes;
    }


}
```

Comment: I see. How would you go about correcting this. My though was to add a j++ after firstp = true. However this got me an indexoutofbounds error.